# Safe encryption for short strings in PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, encryption

this is my first question here:

I want the PHP script to include encrypted user's ID on each page. I will then read it using JS and send it over to Java server where I decode the value.

I want to make it secure-ish so that people cannot fake their IDs. (Don't worry, this will not be used for authentication.)

The encrypted IDs might be MySQL's auto increment column 1,2,3.. and I'm not in a position to change that.

These properties would be nice to have:

- The encrypted IDs should be only valid for a day, ideally for one time use / a second
- The encrypted IDs should not be easily faked (ideally even by the users themselves)

Feel free to suggest other kinds of solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need to decode the ID in Java, or do you just need it for comparison/DB lookup? If you don't need to decode it, a hash could be a potentially more straightforward approach.

Comment: Yes, I need to value to be decoded on the server. I had a typo where I said I would decode in JavaScript, sorry for that!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to re-implement a session. Is there any reason you don't want to use them for this? That way you don't have to pass an ID around and other's can't easily fake them without hijacking another user's session (which HTTPS solves nicely).

Comment: What do you propose? In my scenario a customer inserts a PHP snippet I provide onto his script. That snippet includes my JS on the generated page and calls my server. Thats all changes I get to make to the PHP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a secure hash function to hash a combination of a user id and some value that changes periodically might be a good idea.  For example, you could pick a 128-bit random number each day, then set the ID to be the hash of that value concatenated with the user ID.  Assuming that you use a good hash, like SHA-256, this is cryptographically secure.

Comment: I will go this path with some modification because don't have that kind of control over the PHP server. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of hashing a timestamp with the user ID would probably be best and checking to see the time difference between the timestamp given and the current timestamp. You'll have to ensure the difference acceptance is big enough to account for any server latency though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an algorithm that the numbers have to pass in order to be valid. Bank cards, IMEI (mobile phones) and some other major ones use the Luhn Algorithm - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: This is a fairly intuitive method, however this is assuming he doesn't already have existing user ID's (which surely could only by chance comply to a mod 10 check).

Comment: @jerluc: True. I assumed that there were no existing IDs as if there were, making it so people cannot fake them would be extremely difficult as you would assume they were assigned incrementally.

Comment: @hakunin: Then I think putting something in to stop people faking them is going to be difficult. Although one thing you could do is draw a line under the IDs you have now and start new users using a new method or upgrade existing users with new IDs. Without knowing your setup and scale it would be difficult to say if this is viable though.

Comment: That would work, it is not the case though, where I can change ID generation or previous IDs in any way. Thanks for btinging the issue up, I will have to focus on this too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any to securely decrypt with only JavaScript, as you'd need to include the password in the source code, which isn't very secure.

The best way would be to encrypt and decrypt with PHP: you can call PHP from within JavaScript code (using AJAX.)

So, for example:

encrypt.php

```
<?php 
    $password = "KEYVALUE"; 
    $secret_text = "USERID HERE"
    $encrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $password, $secret_text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT); 
    echo $encrypted_text;
?>
```

Then you have something called decrypt.php, and all that is does is accept a GET argument, and the ONLY output is the decrypted text (no HTML code or anything. Technically you probably should use XML for AJAX, but since it's only one value...)

decrypt.php

```
<?php 
    $password = "KEYVALUE"; 
    $decrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $password, $_GET['decrypt'], MCRYPT_DECRYPT); 
    echo $decrypted_text;
?>
```

You can test this out by calling

> decrypt.php?decrypt=encrypted_string

.

From here I'd call "decrypt.php?decrypt=encrypted_string" script from within JavaScript, and JavaScript can then read the decrypted value.

A quick introduction to AJAX can be found here: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html .

Comment: Exposing a GET request in your JavaScript leaves a huge security hole. If someone with malicious intent were to simply navigate to the decrypt.php page using the query with an encrypted string, he/she would be able to obtain the decrypted value.

Comment: He said he wanted to _obfuscate_. No real cryptography is done here. No need for AJAX in any way.

Comment: I had a typo in the question. I decode it on the server, JS only reads it from html and sends it over. Sorry for that, my bad.